# how to TextView.setText(List<String>object) like TextView.setText(array[index]) settext from List

Tags: java, android

Hello I have a list and i try to do `settext` from it, example I knew that  `TextView.setText(List<String>object)` like `TextView.setText(array[index])`  but it is not working.I tried with get also.Is it the right way to implement custom Adapter:
firtsly I should settext List and then I will add images and so on.
Below is my code :

```
public class GetName  extends Fragment {
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
//ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
 CustomList adapter;

public GetName()
{

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Parse.initialize(getActivity(), "user", "pass");    
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.getnewlay,container, false);


    new GetData().execute();
    return view;
}

private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Parse.com Simple ListView Tutorial");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Name");
        query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
        try {
            ob = query.find();


        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        listview = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listviewget);

        adapter = new CustomList(getActivity(), ob);
                /*ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.listview_item);*/
        // Retrieve object "name" from Parse.com database
        for (ParseObject country : ob) {
            adapter.add((String) country.get("name"));
        }
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

}

Adapter class:

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] descr;
private final Integer[] imageId;
private final Integer[] imagId;*/
private List<ParseObject> ob;

public CustomList(Activity context, List<ParseObject> ob) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_single);
    this.ob = ob;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lname);

    >for(ParseObject i : ob) txtTitle.setText((CharSequence) i);
    >   txtTitle.setText( ob.get(position));

    return rowView;
}
}
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Please post the detail, what your list object is containing, you need to get the a particular object from the list of object and then you can set that to the textview if the object is containg the straing/integer/flot etc.

Comment: @user2163887 here it is

Comment: @Sanjeet Ajnabee can you check

Comment: Still confusing, can you post the entire code?
like List<ParseObject> ob is conatining, perhaps you are working on custom list and adapter. You are taking a bit incorrect approach.

Comment: You need to change this from `txtTitle.setText( ob.get(position));` to `txtTitle.setText( ob.get(position).get("name"));`.

Comment: @Piyush Gupta thank you very much it is really work like a charm post you answer here I will vote up it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this from

```
txtTitle.setText(ob.get(position));
```

to

```
txtTitle.setText(ob.get(position).get("name"));
```

Answer (score 5):

use this

```
TextView.setText(String.valueOf(array[index]));
```

Comment: Yes I have tried text.setText(String.valueOf(od[index]));

Comment: So you getting data ?

Answer (score 3):

Your object should be string. For example,

```
TextView.setText("Your Text");
```

only work.

So try like,

```
TextView.setText(array[index].toString())
```

or

```
TextView.setText(String.valueOf(array[index]))
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

```
textView.setText(array[index].toString());
```

Or simply

```
textView.setText(array[index]+"");
```

Comment: @Jessie have you tried the provided solutions ? .It will work your problem

Comment: is it right that Adapter is extends public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> or it should ArrayAdapter<ParseObject>

Comment: Yes I have tried text.setText(String.valueOf(od[index]));

Comment: Yes I have tried text.setText(String.valueOf(od[index]));

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can do this:

```
TextView.setText(String.valueOf(array[index]));
```

Comment: text.setText(String.valueOf(ob[position])); not worked